# Is it possible to add dropdown in html input tag?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a responsive form in HTML CSS.
Where I want to include the dropdown inside the input tag of HTML

[image]

```
<input type="number" class="form_input" id="pay" placeholder="">
<label for="pay" class="form_label_pay">you pay</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend trying to create invalid html by adding a dropdown inside an input. I recommend you just create the illusion of this effect using styling.

```css
form {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

legend {
  font: 700 12px arial;
  color: #888;
}

.combobox {
  display: flex;
}

.combobox>div {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#payment input {
  text-align: right;
}

#payment input,
#payment select {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: 18px Arial;
}


/*Hide number arrows*/

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Firefox */

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<form id="payment">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>You Pay</legend>
    <div>
      <input id="pay" type="number" class="form_input" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00 ">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>You Receive</legend>
    <div class="combobox">
      <div>
        <input id="receive" type="number" class="form_input" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00 ">
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="payment-provider " id="payment-provider " form="payment ">
          <option value="BitCoin ">BTC</option>
          <option value="Ethereum ">ETH</option>
          <option value="Cardano ">ADA</option>
          <option value="Tether ">USDT</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```